# How to generate _id like elasticsearch but for apache lucene?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I want to generate _id of Elasticsearch document the same way in apache Lucene, to have _id like Elasticsearch but in Apache Lucene.
How can I do?
Where Can I find algorithm that generate Elasticsearch _id?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm is based on [Flake IDs](https://archive.fo/2015.07.08-082503/http://www.boundary.com/blog/2012/01/flake-a-decentralized-k-ordered-unique-id-generator-in-erlang/) and can be found here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/be7c7415627377a1b795400fb8dfcc6cbdf0e322/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/TimeBasedUUIDGenerator.java#L49